# HTTP Proxy with transparent copy

Tags: haproxy, http-proxy

I've got the following:

```
Client -> HAProxy --> backend_service_1
                  --> backend_service_2
```

It's a basic HAProxy Load Balancing config with 2 backend services.

I'm hoping that there's a way for HAProxy (or other HTTP proxy) to do the following **for each request**:

- Proxy the request to backend_service_1 like usual and return the response to the client.
- Proxy the request to backend_service_2 like usual, but ignore the response and don't affect the request going to backend_service_1.

Just in case someone has a better approach, I'm looking to do A/B testing with a "passive" copy of each request going to the new version of the service (backend_service_2 in this case).

Any help is appreciated!